# Multiple watch faces/wearapps for one mobile project

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, wear-os

I'm making an app which needs to be able to connect to multiple watch faces (not at the same time). I have multiple modules in my project. I can't  add

```
wearApp project(':wearApp1')  
wearApp project(':wearApp2')
```

in the same gradle dependencies section.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only have a single Wear module per application, because a requirement for auto-installation is that it have the same package name as its "wrapper" handheld APK. But, you can build that module out with as many watch faces (and whatever else) as you'd like.

A watch face is simply a `Service`, and you're free to include as many `<service />` elements in your manifest as you want. Each will appear as a separate entry in Wear's watch face picker. They can share code or resources if that's helpful to your app's architecture, and in fact doing so is easier when they're all in the same module.

Likewise, that same module can include an `Activity`, or any other Android components you need. It's a full-fledged app, and can be as complex as required.

But you'll definitely need to merge the code into a single wearable module. If you already have these watch faces as separate modules, the easiest route might be to make them into libraries, and just create a single wearable APK that includes them.

Comment: Thank you, this was really helpful!

Comment: Do you know if each <service /> will appear as a separate watch face on a wear device? I will be testing this tonight.

Comment: You probably found out for yourself by now - but yes, each watch face `service` that you define in your manifest will appear as a separate face in the chooser,  both on device and in the handheld  Wear app.